# How to subscribe again to Observable without start new process?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have Observable

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
               Thread.sleep(100);
              subscriber.onNext("Loading:"+i);
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
```

Subscriber

```
 Subscriber<? super String> sub = new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Successfully Done!");
                    pDialog.cancel();
                }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                pDialog.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String string) {
                pDialog.setMessage(string);
            }
        };
```

After click on button I do this:

```
  compositeSubscription.add(observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(
            AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(sub));
```

In Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
   compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
}

 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (!compositeSubscription.isUnsubscribed()&&compositeSubscription.hasSubscriptions())
            compositeSubscription.unsubscribe();
        super.onStop();
    }
```

After clicking on Button, dialog is shown and message is updating.

BUT If I minimize the app and open it again Subscription is lost and message doesn't update, but process continue execute.

**How to subscribe again to Observable without starting new process?**

Comment: The obvious stranger here is `Thread.sleep`. I can't help you right now, but can you re-write using asynchronous operators like `Observable.interval()` and `Observable.take()`? I'll take a look again later if no answer is given.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Thread.sleep - it's added instead of adding BIG code of Http request

Comment: @ReutSharabani how to use this `Observable.take()` ?

Comment: can you at least add this as a comment on your sample code?

Answer (score 2):

1) You're dealing with a *cold observable* here, which means each subscription calls *OnSubscribe.call()* each time you subscribe. You can use  *publish()*  here which converts *Observable* to *ConnectableObservable* or any other operator converting *cold* to *hot*.

2) If you want your *Observable* to keep working after returning from background maybe *onStart/onStop* are not the correct lifecycle callbacks. I'd go for a *onCreate/onDestroy* there

3) Unsubscribing won't stop *OnSubscribe.call()* execution. The easiest solutiion is to check *isUnsubscribed()* inside your loop and stop accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Subject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/subject):

```
Observable<Long> observable = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();
observable.subscribe(subject);

Subscription subscription = subject.subscribe(o -> {
    System.out.println("o = " + o);
});

Thread.sleep(500);
subscription.unsubscribe();

Subscription subscription2 = subject.subscribe(o -> {
    System.out.println("continued = " + o);
});

Thread.sleep(500);
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

This will produce the following output:

```
o = 0
o = 1
o = 2
o = 3
o = 4
continued = 5
continued = 6
continued = 7
continued = 8
continued = 9
```